# Is it possible to catch any exception thrown by an object in it's factory?

Tags: php, oop, exception

For example:

```
class Test{

    public function doStuff(){
        throw new Exception("Something gone wrong...");
    }

}

class TestFactory{

    public static function getTest(){

        try{
            $testObj = new Test();
            return $testObj;
        }catch(Exception $e){
            //... handle $e ...
            throw new Exception("Exception from factory");
        }

    }

}
```

When I call "doStuff()", its possible to throw "Exception from factory" instead of "Something gone wrong..." ?

```
$obj = TestFactory::getTest();
$obj->doStuff(); //Called outside TestFactory
```

Comment: I've tried it already, @DanyalSandeelo, it still throws _Something gone wrong..._

Comment: that means it  does, because you are catching the excepting that is thrown by the constructor..

Comment: @jeroen, it could be called anywhere, inside a controller method, or by a component

Comment: If it is not in the `try` block in the factory, it will not be catched there and re-thrown.

Comment: What's the concrete case where you'd need this and why? A factory isn't enough to create this behaviour, you'd need to `extend Test` with another class with overrides `doStuff` and catches and rethrows the exception.

Comment: As a side note: `static` factories aren't terrifically useful, they provide little benefit over directly writing `new Test` and are mostly missing the point.

Comment: @deceze The case is I'm extending Pdo and PdoStatement, that throws PdoException in methods like "execute", "prepare" , etc...
I have my CustomException class that log those errors and i would like to throw it instead of PdoException, whenever its thrown

Comment: @deceze The Factory example was used because its the concept of _Pdo::prepare_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `try` catches errors only within its scope. In your example it will catch exceptions in the `Test::__construct` only. As soon as object is returned from the factory, it left the `try/catch` scope.

You can handle `"Something gone wrong..."` this way:

```
try {
    $obj = TestFactory::getTest();
    $obj->doStuff(); //Called outside TestFactory
} catch(Exception $e) {
    //... handle $e ...
}
```

Comment: So, maybe its a way to hook "doStuff" method? Or shall I overwrite the method in a child class of test?

Comment: You can hook and overwrite if you like. I have updated the answer to show where to catch the exception.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Alex, it is not possible to catch exceptions in the factory method, because when the exception occurs, the factory method is long finished.

From [op's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416246/is-it-possible-to-catch-any-exception-thrown-by-an-object-in-its-factory#comment56575159_34416246)

> The case is I'm extending Pdo and PdoStatement, that throws PdoException in methods like "execute", "prepare" , etc... I have my CustomException class that log those errors and i would like to throw it instead of PdoException, whenever its thrown

PDO will by itself always throw PDOExceptions. I don't think we should change PDO code in a way that it throws other types of Exceptions, nor should we ever throw PDOExceptions ourselves.

What we can do however, is catch those PDOExceptions and throw our CustomExceptions on top of it:

```
public function doStuff()
{
    try { /* PDO code that can throw PDOException */ }
    catch (\PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        throw new CustomPDOException("Something gone wrong", $ex->getCode(), $ex); 
    }
}
```

You have to wrap your code in a way to catch all errors that can be thrown by PDO.

Comment: Great answer. I will extend all my database exceptions from PdoException. :)

The fact is you can set a custom class to be your statement: `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, ['\\App\\CustomStatement', []]);` and , to me, you should be able to setup custom exceptions aswell.
As PDO itsel lack this, i was trying to search a workaround with pure php